# How do I hide this CSS element?

Tags: css, wordpress

```
<section class="mesh_section type-mesh_section status-publish hentry">
```

How do I hide the above? I've tried the with the post ID at the front

```
.postid-11319 .mesh_section { display: none}
```

I've even put the display none code under Inspect element under this and it works fine.

```
element.style {
}
```

There's a whole section I need hidden.

Image here of full code:

[image: code screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with you example. First `.postid-11319` doesn't select something with the `id="postid-11319"` but `class="postid-11319"`. To select by `id` you should use the `#` operator like:

```css
#postid-11319 .mesh_section { display: none; }
```

For you interest, the inspector propose you to update the styles of an element by using `element.style {}` but that's only working in the scope of the inspector to easily design something with CSS.

Comment: I've used the .postid-11319 for other things on that page and it's worked. Also, using # instead doesn't seem to have worked either.

Answer (score -2):

Are you open to using JQuery?

Your JQuery Function would look a little like this

```
$( ".mesh_section" ).hide();
```

I've founding using `display: none` can cause issues like the element appearing and disappearing

Alternatively you can add  `display: none` inline

`<section style="display:none" class="mesh_section type-mesh_section status-publish hentry"> </section>`